# physical block size is 2048 bytes, but Linux says it is 512

Tags: usb

I know that this error message is haunting so many people that try to format a USB drive. But when I search for it, all I get is "instructions". But I really want to **understand** the technical background on this matter.

I have read a lot about sectors, cylinders, blocks etcetera ... I've understood it all so I think I have a solid background now.

In all the tutorials that I've read, nobody mentioned "physical block size". But from my understanding so far I would translate it into "sector size on the device". Correct?

I think (I didn't find confirmation anywhere for this) that the "USB device descriptor" is stored somewhere by the "controller". It is not part of the NAND flash chip. I imagine it works like this: my OS sends some sort of GET request to the controller chip of the USB. The controller chip returns the "device descriptor". That "device descriptor" contains information such as vendor AND sector size (= physical block size??).

That is how my OS knows about the physical block size. But how on earth would "Linux claim it's 512" ??? Where is that information stored, how does Linux come to that claim?

Comment: 512 x 32 bit words?

Comment: uhm, excuse me?

Comment: maybe it is four 512 byte sectors in a 2048 byte cluster ( 4 sector cluster )

Comment: I don't think the information is exposed in an official, standard way by the flash memory firmware. Some manufacturers may provide non-standard commands to get there. But it's not reliable. USB flash memory drives do wear-leveling and have "converged" on the 512-byte "block size," irrespective of their actual physical sectoring. (There may be some programs that may attempt some non-standard means to get this information, though. A Linux driver isn't going to worry about it. So it will report what the device reports. And that will in general NOT be its physical sectoring.)

Comment: Could you show result of `hdparm -I /dev/sdX | grep -i physical`

Comment: You say "this error message", but it's not clear what error message you're talking about. Is the question itself the text of an error message? If so, what tool produced the message and what were you asking it to do when you got that message?

Comment: I don't think any flash or HDD drives expose the physical sector size as 2048 bytes. Most of them have 512-byte or 4096-byte sector. Only CDs and DVDs have 2048-byte sector

Comment: The most satisfying explanation I've heard is that the disk image has an iso9660 (cdrom) filesystem, and that filesystem claims the disk uses 2k sectors (because cdroms do). However, the filesystem is written as a file directly to a disk (flash drive), which uses 512 byte sectors. This mismatch causes the confusion of some tools such as `parted -l` or gparted, since they recognize that there's an iso filesystem present, but its information doesn't match the information presented by the drive.

Answer (score 1):

Quick overview (if you really want to understand all the details, you'll have to read the standards, which are all available online):

The USB protocol for storage devices is more or less identical to the commands that were used for [SCSI](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SCSI) devices. So you have commands to read and write blocks, and a bunch of other commands. Among those is `READ CAPACITY(16)` (the 16 means the command is 16 bytes long, an earlier variant was only 10 bytes long), which returns, among some other information, both the size of logical blocks and how many logical blocks are there per physical block.

So that's how the OS knows about the logical and physical block size. The response information is stored in the firmware of the controller, not on the storage medium.

Now it can happen that for USB-harddisks, which consist of a SATA-drive and a USB-to-SATA bridge chip, that this bridge chip is buggy and doesn't properly forward the answer of the `READ CAPACITY` command (I have a drive with such a chip, and I confirmed a get a different answer via SATA for the same disk). In that case, even if the harddisk claims correctly to have a physical block size of 2048, the bridge chip will mangle this answer so the OS gets an identical physical and logical block size back. So that's the usual reason for the situation when the reported block size is wrong.

For USB flash sticks, the situation is again different: There's no SATA drive behind a bridge, the controller and the flash ROM of the USB stick form a tight unit, and if the controller is lying about the physical block size, then it is lying about it - nothing one can do. Actually, you won't even now it is lying, because while flash ROM does have erase blocks which would justify a "physical block size", you don't know their size.

It wasn't really clear from your question if you are talking about USB harddisks or USB flash ROMs - for modern harddisks one can assume that they have a physical block size of 2048, for flash ROMs one can't assume anything, so your claim "physical block size is 2048" in that case is a bit questionable, unless you can explain how you know that.

And finally: A "USB device descriptor" is part of the USB protocol itself, and a completely different thing.

Answer (score 0):

I think you are confusing the physical characteristics of the flash chip with the settings of the operating system and file system.

The flash chip will have some block or sector size, which is the smallest unit of memory that can be electrically  erased and written. A block size of 2048 bytes is not uncommon. Again, this is a physical characteristic of the flash circuitry...similar to the sectors of a rotating magnetic hard drive.

The filesystem block size is the smallest unit of memory that the operating system will use to store a file or part of a file. This is usually specified when the media (e.g. flash drive) is first formatted, and can only be changed if you reformat the storage media. If you choose a small block size (and 512 bytes is a small block size) then less memory is wasted when storing files. On the other hand, choosing a large block size means that there is less fragmentation of a large file when it is stored. Usually, a larger block size (say 4096 bytes) is used when the volume has a larger capacity.

Comment: thank you but I know all of this already, can you answer my last 2 questions? maybe I have to rephrase: if the sector size IS (physical fact!) 2048 bytes, why would Linux say "no it's not, it's 512". Which process leads the OS to that conclusion? Which file did it read, which information was retrieved from where, which interpolation was made, TO get to that result? Why does Linux say something that isn't true?

Comment: You need to supply more information. In **exactly** what context does Linux "say" that the sector size is 512 bytes? How do you **know** that the actual sector size is 2048 bytes? You need to be much more specific than "the OS says so".